# RGraph Line Charts X Axis label to be grouped by Month on Year

Tags: javascript, charts, rgraph

Can I have X Axis labels to Show Month(names) be grouped on Year in a Line chart.
Image attached to this post : [X Axis Month-names grouped by Year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vk9K0.png)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet there is to use the drawing API text object to add the extra year labels. Do the months with the regular Scatter/Line labels.

Comment: Thanks Richard, Well, I tried. The issue with this is finding the distance/area for the year label. On X Axis there might be 12 months of the same year OR 3 months of 'first' year ....12 month of 'second' year and 3 months of 'third' year... well it might go in any combination of year(s). Any suggestion, please.

Comment: You'll have to do maths I'm afraid. eg spacing = (canvaswidth - gutterleft - gutterright) / (numpoints - 1 - (2 * hmargin) ) That will give you the space between each point. So the first year starts at the first point: (gutterleft + hmargin) and the second point at (gutterleft + hmargin + spacing) and the third point at (gutterleft + hmargin + (2* spacing) ) and so on.